# jquery not enabling/disabling drop down option based on other drop down option

Tags: jquery

I am using the following jquery code in order to have the following happen

```
if remote_server is "yes" 
     allow all fields under FTP
else remote_server is "no"
     disable all fields under FTP
```

The issue I am running into is that changing "remote_server" to no does not disable the "ftp_mode" drop down option but does disable all the text boxes.  If I am setting "remote_server" to yes then all the boxes are enabled with the exception of the "ftp_mode" drop down option

JQ code

```
var e = document.getElementsByName("remote_server")[0]
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

$('select[name=remote_server]').change(function(){
   var inputs = $('input[name^=ftp_],select[name^=ftp_]');
   $(this).val() == "0" ? inputs.attr("disabled", "disabled") : inputs.removeAttr("disabled");
}).change()
```

Here is the HTML to both options:

Remote_server:

```
<select name="remote_server" class="required">
<option></option>
<option value="1" <?php if($remote=="1") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Yes</option>
<option value="0" <?php if($remote=="0") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>No</option>
</select>
```

ftp_mode

```
<select name="ftp_mode" class="required">
<option></option>
<option value="1" <?php if($ftpmode=="1") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Active</option>
<option value="0" <?php if($ftpmode=="0") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Passive</option>
</select>
```

Comment: seems like its working http://jsfiddle.net/2MDCV/

Comment: Also you can use `var strUser = $('[name="remote_server"] option:selected').val();` to get the selected option's value.

Comment: hmm i see it working on jsfiddle but i cant understand why its not working on my server.  could i be missing something server side? perhaps im missing jquery being loaded correctly or something?